# GCE API for differential snapshots

Tags: google-compute-engine

With gcloud it is possible to create differential snapshots of your instances, so you can save space and do not need to create full snapshots all the time.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks#snapshots

I checked the [GCE API reference](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/disks/createSnapshot) and there is no parameter for source snapshot.

Is there any way to use the API to create a differential Snapshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no specific API to request differential snapshot. Differential snapshots are automatically taken after the first full snapshot. You don't need to remember which source snapshot to use and you don't need to worry about making the call with the right parameters to benefit from differential snapshots. It's all taken care for you automatically.

Cheers,
Fabricio.

Comment: Thanks Fabrico. If I list the snapshots, they always show the full disk size. I don't know how much space a snapshot really uses, is there a command for that? Will you always be billed for the full size, or only for differential size?

Comment: UPDATE: There is no command to show the real snapshot size (not yet). You will always be billed for the real snapshot size.